# KALI LINUX accidently disabled visual mode

Tags: graphics, mode

I am a beginner in Kali Linux and I messed up:

I wanted to set my VPN connection and after installation, Kali Linux started in **command mode**

I used `services.list` from some forum and these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
apt-get install network-manager-pptp
apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome
apt-get install network-manager-strongswan
apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

How can I get out of Command Mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -f gdm3
```

To reinstall Gnome Display Manager. Reboot afterwards.

Comment: Mmm ty but intime of processing las comand (apt-get install -f gdm3) suddenly switched to blackscreen with coursor in left corner and freezed.. useless aftet reboot too.... i will reinstal whole sys